# pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Fully qualified namespace is too long

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

i am trying to update the document in existing collection in mongodb using below sample code

```python
update_query = {
            'filter_document': filter_document,
            '$set': update_document
        }
# Perform the update using update_one
result = target_table_name.update_one(filter_document, {'$set': update_document})
```

but getting some namespace error

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Fully qualified namespace is too long.
Namespace: 657054a9d9f79301cdb248ba_cdc.Collection(
   ', '], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True,
authsource='admin', replicaset='atlas-givhqi-shard-0', tls=True
), 'cdc'), 'a') Max: 255,
full error: {
  'ok': 0.0,
  'errmsg': "Fully qualified namespace is too long. Namespace: .Collection(Database7', \', \'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, authsource='admin', replicaset='atlas-givhqi-shard-0', tls=True), 'cdc'), 'a') Max: 255",
'code': 73,
'codeName': 'InvalidNamespace',
'$clusterTime': {
  'clusterTime': Timestamp(1701864161, 2),
  'signature': {
    'hash': b'C\xef\xb20LK\xc8\x9f5#\xcd\xd7\x03\xc2C\xff8\xbb\x1f^',
    'keyId': 7309381498468040709}
  },
  'operationTime': Timestamp(1701864161, 2)
}
```

i have tried to shortening the collection name but still getting same error

Comment: Please show how `target_table_name` gets assigned a value.

Comment: That looks like the collection name is `', '], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True,authsource='admin', replicaset='atlas-givhqi-shard-0', tls=True`
 Perhaps there is a problem in the code that generates the collection name?

Comment: i am getting the target_table_name & below is the output of update_query

{'filter_document': {'student_id': 108}, '$set': {'is_active': False, 'modified_dt': datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 6, 11, 21, 42, 690000), 'is_deleted': True, 'created_dt': datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 5, 14, 2, 37, 207000), 'student_id': 108, 'student_name': 'Saru K'}}\n"

Comment: @VipulGabhane  Please edit your question to include new/updated information.  It will help current and future readers.  Formatting, etc., is limited in comments.